# Porting My Linux Compiler to Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assembly, compiler-construction, x86-64

I am designing a programming language and have completed a compiler that generates x86 assembly code that works in Linux.

Specifically, my compiler takes as input a "myprogram.stanza" text file and generates an "myprogram.s" text file containing the x86 instructions to be assembled and linked by the GCC toolchain.

I would like now to be able to support Windows as well. What is the most straightforward way of doing that? Specifically:

1) Is Visual Studio the "standard" toolchain for Windows?

2) I want to be able to generate an assembly file and have it compile naturally with the rest of a large C/C++ project. What assembler should I be targeting?

Thanks very much for your help.

-Patrick

Comment: I'm sure microsoft would just LOVE to have VS the "standard". but no, you can't depend on it being present. it's **A** toolchain, not **THE** toolchain.

Comment: gnu assembler runs on windows as well yes?

Comment: there are lots of compilers for windows: Intel compiler, gcc (and its "variants"), clang, tcc... not only VS

Comment: You probably want to target [MASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afzk3475.aspx) for your assembly code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two major [assembly syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language) are:

-`Intel Syntax`: [opcode] [destination], [origin] (ex: mov eax, 10)
-`AT&T Syntax`: [opcode] [origin], [destination] (ex: movl $10, %eax)

Because you where targeting GCC you most probably was generating assembly in `AT&T syntax`.

Most assembler of the common toolchain in Windows use `Intel Syntax`, Visual Studio assembler use `Intel Syntax`, MASM and NASM too.

Question 1) Yes Visual Studio is the defacto toolchain in Windows (this don't mean that it's the only one or the better or anything, but it's the most used toolchain when working in Windows). GCC work in Windows, Intel Compiler integrate very well with VS and Embarcadero is leading the way of clang base compiler in Windows. When you are working in multi plataform project the common used compilers combination are `GCC - VC++` (by far) and `Intel,GCC - Intel,GCC`.

Question 2) If you would like to assemble in Windows with the common toolchain you would need to generate `Intel Syntax`, if you have `AT&T Syntax` already working would be fast enough. My recommendation here if you like to push the project forward is to use for example LLVM or another library, to translate your language source code into intermediate representation (ex: LLVM IR) and from there to assembler (note: LLVM handle AT&T and Intel syntax)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply. It seems that VC is not entrenched enough that I would be seriously harming myself by requiring a gcc toolchain. I will continue generating AT&T syntax for use with the gas assembler, and just make sure that I am not overly reliant on Posix functions.